# When is a particle speeding up/down based on position graph

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image]

**Question:** Based on this position graph of a particle, how am I supposed to know when it is speeding up or slowing down?

I know that with a velocity graph, when velocity and acceleration have the same sign the object is speeding up and when they differ it is slowing down, but how do I apply this to a velocity graph? My best guess is $[0,1) \cup (3,4)$ for speeding up and the inverse for slowing down, but my homework says that's wrong. Help, please?

Comment: Have you tried sketching the first and second derivative graphs?

Comment: @EricSnyder I don't think I would be able to accurately sketch the derivative graphs without the actual equation. My main problem would be the original rate of change. For x=0, would the derivative be 0 as it is a starting point or would it be a different value (and would that be positive or negative?). Thanks

Comment: The first derivative is the slope of the tangent to the curve. What kind of slope does the tangent have a $x = 0$?